# Getting data from DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, api-gateway

I want to fetch the data from Dynamo-Db Table using primary key using python.
My Table name is "CustomerDetails" and primary key is "Email-id".
I will trigger this Lambda function from API Gateway.

```
      import boto3
      from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
      dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
      table = dynamodb.Table('CustomerDetails')
      def lambda_handler(event, context):
           response = table.get_item(key={'Email-id':event})
           #response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('Email-id').eq(event))
```

Above code is not working. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Deleted my answer because, as Mark B noted, I was looking at dynamodbClient instead of dynamodb.Table
That being said, could you please provide the response from the table.get_item() call?

Answer (score 1):

You must change the `get_item(key=` to `get_item(Key=` and I think you might inform the proper place to retrieve the email_id from the event.

Here is an example:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def lambda_handler(event, context):
      dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
      table = dynamodb.Table('CustomerDetails')
      email_id = event['xxx']['xxxx'] # where your email id is in the event dict

      response = table.get_item(Key={'Email-id': email_id}).get('Item')

      ...
```